# How to accept inputs with Scanner without spaces in Java?

Tags: java, input, int, output, space

```
public static String countPairs(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4) {
    String Pairs = "";

    if (i1 == i2 && i3 == i4) Pairs = ("two pairs");
    else if (i1 == i3 && i2 == i4) Pairs = ("two pairs");
    else if (i1 == i4 && i2 == i3) Pairs = ("two pairs");
    else Pairs = ("not two pairs");

    return Pairs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter four numbers: ");
    int int1 = in.nextInt();
    int int2 = in.nextInt();
    int int3 = in.nextInt();
    int int4 = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print(countPairs(int1, int2, int3, int4));
```

Here is my code which reads four integers and prints “two pairs” if the input consists of two matching pairs (in some order) and “not two pairs” otherwise.

When I use the Scanner I want the input to accept: 1221 (without spaces) but if I don't put the spaces myself it doesn't output anything. I have to write it like: 1 2 2 1 to get the output. Is there to make it accept the input without spaces?

Comment: Take the input in as a string and split on every character, or use modulus to get each digit, then parse as needed and send to metho.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scanner.nextLine()  for this.

```
int int1 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());   
int int2 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
int int3 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
int int4 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "1234";
int[] num = new int[a.length()];
for(int x = 0; x< a.length(); x++) num[x] = Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(x));
System.out.println(countPairs(num[0], num[1], num[2], num[3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
String toParse = scan.nextLine();  // here you can pass 1234
```

Then split the variable "toParse" and put it into an array of Strings

```
String toParse = scan.nextLine();
String [] toParseArr = toParse.split("");
for(int i=0; i<toParseArr.length; ++i){
    //obtain values here and do something
}
```